# How do I copy a python dictionary into a 2d dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading a file with system information line-by-line and when I see an equal-sign, convert it into a key:value entry in a standard dictionary until I reach a line that ends the individual system's info.
I then want to copy that dictionary into a 2d dictionary - i.e. dict2[dict1[name]] = {dict1.key = dict1.value} iterating over the keys, then repeat this for the next system.

I keep getting syntax errors on the 2d setup:

Here is sample input:

```
Host is linux4493

Name = linux4493
Class = Linux
Family = Hardware.Server
Host Name = linux4493
Serial Number = KQ72BWY
MAC Address = 34:40:b5:aa:24:14
DNS Name = ;;
EIT Managed? =
BU =
Location =
1. CMDB Attributes
  1. Attributes
                Memory Installed = 72GB
                Disk Capacity = 1394.18GB
                Processor Type = Xeon
                Processor Cache = 12MB
                Processor Speed =  2.67GHz
                Processor Sockets = 2
                Number of Physical Processors Installed = 2
                Number of Cores per Processor = 6
                Number of Memory Slots = 18
                OS Version = RHEL6
                Primary Application = InfraRed5

  6. Inventory
                IP Address = 192.168.1.41
                Install Date = 09/28/2012 12:55 PM
```

Host is rh6u3x64mt

```
TOP OF FORM
Name = rh6u3x64mt
Class = Linux_VM
Family = Hardware.Virtual Machine
Host Name = rh6u3x64mt
Serial Number = VMware-42 00 bf 4c 39 d0 29 92-a5 dd 45 02 a4 d7 a2 79
Virtual MAC Address = 00:50:56:80:00:99
Virtual Host Name = rh6u3x64mt.test.com
EIT Managed? =
BU =
Location =

1. CMDB Attributes
        1. Attributes
                Memory Installed = 16GB
                Disk Capacity = 4336.00GB
                Processor Type = Xeon
                Processor Speed =  2.00GHz
                Number of Virtual Processors = 2
                Memory Minimum = 2GB
                Memory Allocated = 16GB
                OS Version = RHEL6
                Primary Application = Metrotech
                Cluster Name =

        6. Inventory
                IP Address = 192.168.8.110
                Installation Date = 09/27/2012 10:45 AM
```

Here's the code:

```
import os, getopt, sys, fileinput
from array import *

sysarray = {}
entryarr = {}

for rline in fileinput.input():
    if "=" in rline:
        (rlkey, rlval) = rline.split("=")
        if rlkey.strip() == "Virtual Host Name":
            rlkey = "DNS Name"
        entryarr[rlkey.strip()] = rlval.strip()
        if "Install" in rline:
            list(entryarr)
            for ky in entryarr.keys():
                sysarray[entryarr[Name]] = { ky = entryarr[ky]r})
```

I cant seem to fine the correct syntax for that last line.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be simpler to show a sample input file and the resulting dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean `dict2[dict1["name"]] = dict1`?

Answer (score 1):

I coudn't understand what exactly you want to do.

But, if you want to do something like this:

```
sysarray = {
    'file1': {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    },
    'file2': {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    }
}
```

You can change your last lines from:

```
if "Install" in rline:
    list(entryarr)
    for ky in entryarr.keys():
        sysarray[entryarr[Name]] = { ky = entryarr[ky]r})
```

to:

```
if "Install" in rline:
    sysarray[filename] = entryarr
```